# Java Guava combination of Multimap and Cache

Tags: java, guava, multimap

Is there any such thing as a combination of Guava's `Cache` and `Multimap` functionality available? Essentially, I need a collection where entries expire after a given time such as available in `Cache` but I have non-unique keys and I need the entries to expire independently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that Louis Wasserman provided the answer in one of the comments above, i.e. that there is no off-the-shelf combo of `Multimap` and `Cache` available. I have solved my problem/requirements with the solution outlined in pseudo-code below:

```
private Cache<Integer,Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().SomeConfig.build();
private Multimap<Integer,Object> multimap = HashMultimap<Integer, Object>.create();
private AtomicInteger atomicid = new AtomicInteger(0);

public void putInMultimap(int id, Object obj) {
   int mapid = atomicid.addAndGet(1);
   cache.put(mapid,obj);
   multimap.put(id,mapid);
}
public List<Object> getFromMultimap(int id) {
   Set<Integer> mapids = multimap.get(id);
   List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
   for (int i : mapids) {
      list.add(cache.getIfPresent(i));
   }
   return list;
}
```

This simple 'solution' has some limitations but it works OK for me.

Comment: How do you deal with the ever-growing multimap?

Comment: @neu242 for the `SomeConfig` part in the current answer you can add a `.removalListener` call there, which will be called whenever something is evicted from the cache, so that you can also remove it from the multimap

Answer (score 0):

With a Guava Cache there is no **put** method, the cache is designed to be self-populating.  The values returned from a key lookup are calculated at runtime.  A similar approach is taken by Commons Collections Transformer Factories.

I think you could implement what you are looking for quite easily.  If you look at a simple Map backed example such as [Kitty-Cache](http://code.google.com/p/kitty-cache/) you can see that you could replace the Map with a Multimap and rewrite the other methods accordingly.  So in [KittyCache.java](http://code.google.com/p/kitty-cache/source/browse/trunk/src/main/java/com/spaceprogram/kittycache/KittyCache.java) internally you could have something like:

```
Multimap<K, CacheEntry<V>> cache;
```

The trick for this kind of cache is that nothing really expires until someone requests it.

Comment: "With a Guava Cache there is no put method, the cache is designed to be self-populating" -- this isn't true. It is true `Cache` itself has no method "put" and that `LoadingCache` is designed to be self-populating, but you can always use a non-loading cache, and call `cache.asMap().put(...)` to add your own entries. Of course, this doesn't get you a multimap. Just correcting that first statement.

Comment: Since Guava 11.0 there is a [put method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#put(K, V)) in `Cache`. The example you provided is interesting but I cannot rely on expiration on requests, I implement `RemovalListener`'s to get notification on expirations in the `Cache`.

Comment: Thanks for putting this straight Ray.  I was quoting: http://java.dzone.com/articles/google-guava-cache

Comment: Of course hgus1294 is right--`put` was added in 11.0. My mistake.

Comment: Mark, I believe that article was published shortly before 11.0 was released, hence the confusion.

Comment: For info: "Caches built with CacheBuilder do not perform cleanup and evict values "automatically," or instantly after a value expires, or anything of the sort. Instead, it performs small amounts of maintenance during write operations, or during occasional read operations if writes are rare."  See: http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Removal_Listeners

Comment: All this said, `Multimap` implementations are extremely nontrivial, and our internal implementations aren't designed to handle cache entries expiring.  This would be a pretty major project. =/

Comment: @LouisWasserman 'Major project', so not before end of month? Just kidding, I appreciate the feedback Louis. Thanks

Comment: ...It _could_ be a month-long project to get something that manages to correctly satisfy the `Multimap` contract.  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you're talking about `Cache` and not `LoadingCache` you could pass the `Cache.asMap()` view into `Multimaps.newMultimap`.

Comment: Interesting. I did some testing but I cannot get the entries to expire independently. I passed a `Cache.asMap()` into a `Multimaps.newMultimap` according to your suggestion and did some quick testing with with `expireAfterWrite` set to 1000 ms and ran the following scenario:
`map.put(1,Object1);` `Thread.Sleep(700)` `map.put(1,Object2);` `Thread.Sleep(500)`. At this point I expect the first entry to be evicted but the second to remain but I find both entries to be evicted. Maybe I am doing something wrong but unless I can change the behavior, it does not work for me.